# Maven commons-configuration2

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

I am using Apache `commons-configuration2` in one of my projects. Recently, I decided to let Maven manage my projects. Which works fine, except for `commons-configuration2`; I am not able to find that dependency on the Maven repo. Even when looking just for `commons-configuration`, not `commons-configuration2`, none of the results I am getting are `org.apache.commons`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's because version `1.x` of the artifact `commons-configuration` was under the `commons-configuration` group. It was only after it became `commons-configuration2` (technically an entirely different artifact), it was grouped under `org.apache.commons`. You don't see them in the maven repo probably because it's still a [`SNAPSHOT`](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-configuration2/). See the [project page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/project-summary.html) for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because, version `1.x` of the artifact `commons-configuration` was really under the `commons-configuration` group. You can find the latest `release` version, `1.10`, of that artifact in the [repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.10).

It was only after it became `commons-configuration2` (technically an entirely different Maven artifact of the same project), it was grouped under `org.apache.commons`. You don't see them in the maven repo (the `RELEASE` repo that is) probably because it's still a `SNAPSHOT`. You can still find the artifact in the [`SNAPSHOT` repo](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-configuration2/).

See the [project summary](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/project-summary.html) and [release history](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/changes-report.html) for more information.

Comment: @mystarrocks: Do you happen to know where to find the Maven artifact for `org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.0-beta1`? It doesn't seem to be in the snapshot repo you linked.

Comment: @Virtlink [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33633215/934307) answer below explains why you can't/won't find it.

Comment: now, you can directly find the artifact `org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.1.1`. Here is the [link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22commons-configuration2%22)

Answer (score 2):

Current workaround solution:

1. [Download](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/download_configuration.cgi) Apache Commons Configuration 2.0 and got the `commons-configuration2-2.0-beta2.jar`
2. Add the `commons-configuration2-2.0-beta2.jar` to external library
3. Add the [needed dependency](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/dependencies.html) in maven.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
       <version>1.9</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
       <version>1.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
       <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`commons-configuration2` now available on Maven Central: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2

Answer (score 1):

A [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION-606) has been filed against the documentation (or against the repo, depending on your view). Apparently, `commons-configuration2` will not be pushed to Maven central until final release, but the documentation on their website is automatically generated and points you to a non-existent repository. This will be fixed when a final release is done.

Answer (score 1):

`commons-configuration2-2.1` is now available in the [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2/2.1).